# How to the get the position of a UISwitch inside a UICollectionViewCell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uiswitch

I have a `UICollectionView` with an `UIImageView` and a `UISwitch`. On clicking the `UISwitch` I want to retrieve the index of the `Cell`.

I am able to retrieve the index of the cell on clicking the `UIImageView` in the cell but not the switch using `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The cell will not be selected when switching the UISwitch, so you have to use other means to identify the item.

Usually this is done by:

- using a dedicated target for the switch
- or using a tag to identify the switch

Answer (score 0):

This would be the desired solution for you where I have used the `tableView` method to get the `indexPath` depending on the button location in `tableView`

```
func switchTap(sender: UISwitch) {
     //Get the point in cell
    let center: CGPoint = sender.center;
    let rootViewPoint: CGPoint = sender.superview.convertPoint(center, toView: tableView)
     // Now get the indexPath
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(rootViewPoint)
}
```